# Cryptic Chamber *1* (discontinued)

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, locks

(discontinued puzzle)

The remake for this puzzle is out.

> You wake up. Eyes wide open, you sit up, with a terrible pain in your stomach. You're inside a dark room, and you see a light above a light switch. You get up, walk towards the switch, you flip it, and the room you are in is illuminated. There is writing on the wall:
>
> > Hello, contestant. You have been chosen to be a test subject in my testing chamber. As you can see, there are several items around the room you need to put to use to get to the next room. You have two options: You can either stay here and starve to death, or you can get through all five rooms in this chamber, and reach freedom. Each room is more difficult than the next. I'll take a load off of you and make this room simple for you. Just don't break the light switch, and don't break the door or the lock - You'll instantly lose, and I'll kill you. And no breaking the walls or the roof, or the floor, I'll kill you if you do that as well. Good luck - and don't die.
>
> OBJECTIVE {GET TO THE NEXT ROOM}
>
> You look around the room. There's a metal door with a locked padlock on it, made with very strong metal. You remember you are great at picking locks (not that you were a burglar or anything). But what are you going to pick the lock with? You look around the room for anything else that might help you. You see a slightly soft metal wire on the ground. You think you can use it to pick the lock - wait nevermind it's too big lol
>
> A stainless steel water pipe goes across the ceiling of the room. One of the parts are loose. You can already hear water rushing out of it - It reminds you you're thirsty.
>
> SIDE OBJECTIVE (QUENCH YOUR THIRST)
>
> There are a few bricks laying in a pile on the corner of the room.
>
> The ceiling is a few feet higher than you.
>
> How do you get to the second room?
>
> OBJECTIVES {GET TO THE NEXT ROOM} (QUENCH YOUR THIRST)
>   Objectives in {} are the main objective. Objectives in () are side objectives.
>
> How do you get to the next room?

Rules: No breaking the lock, the door, the walls, the roof, or the floor. The only way to get to the next room is to pick the lock. You can only pound the metal wire with other metal.

Comment: This needs more detail or clarification on what could/could not work. As it is, you are going to get a lot of speculative answers. I'm flagging it as "too broad".

Comment: Do you simply "walk towards" the switch before the room was lit, or did you actually flip it?

Comment: How do you "see a light switch" in a dark room?

Comment: @BenDover You created a story puzzle with very little in the way of rules. You are trying to translate a physical situation onto paper, and without witnessing your scenario firsthand, we can only throw out suggestions of which there are nearly unlimited possibilities.

Comment: You just aren't very experienced yet. Rather than getting upset, take the opportunity to learn. You already know the answer, so you see the solution as obvious. You need to remove yourself from the situation and think of yourself as a solver. "I AM this character that I wrote in - I don't know what's happening. What do I try?" If there are possibilities that you haven't accounted for, maybe there needs to be a reason for you NOT to do that in the story.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would

> take the soft metal wire and put it on a brick and use another brick to pound it until it is thin enough to work.

And after you do this

> but right before you leave, smash the loose pipe to get some water leaking or flowing and quench your thirst

Comment: I didn’t see this when I posted, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if something like this would work, but

> assuming you can get to the water, hold the metal thing under it until it weakens (idk chemistry at all, no idea if this would work) and then smash it with bricks until it’s small enough. Then use it to pick the lock.

Answer (score 1):

To get to the next room, you...

> Smash the padlock with a brick.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't the answer... Keep trying, though!

Comment: @BenDover two bricks?

Comment: wth no m8 :P you can't smash the lock with bricks :P

Answer (score 1):

SteveV's answer is looking promising. Alternatively...

> Your stomach hurts because you've been made to swallow a key/bobby pin/lockpick tool/etc. You make yourself sick or wait for it to pass and use that to undo the padlock.

Comment: His answer does look good, but you aren't allowed to smash the wire with bricks. Just look at the rules at the bottom of the puzzle. I'm working on the second part right now, so I won't have time to answer questions for the next few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how likely this is but

> hope that the wire happens to be iron, hit the pipe with a brick, drink some of the water, and also use the water to rust the wire, using a brick to scrape off the rust as well, until it's small enough to use to pick the lock

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with new rules.

> use a brick to break of some of the pipe, then smash the wire with *that* and pick the lock with it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it looks like we are nearing the answer piecemeal...

> You dislodge the pipe from the ceiling. You slake your thirst. You use the pipe to smash the wire down into a workable size, then pick the lock with that.